# What is the Windows overhead when using SQL Server varchar vs. nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6, varchar, nvarchar

I do not have need for foreign language characters or collation since my data is received as pure ascii.

My concern is performance in the application code, and though I have read many arguments that varchar performs better than nvarchar, they did not discuss the overhead converting back and forth between Windows Unicode and SQL Server non-Unicode varchar data?

What is the bigger impact in general - performance within SQL Server dealing with varchar vs. nvarchar, or performance in the application, converting back and forth between Unicode on the Windows side and non-Unicode on the SQL Server side? I understand there are scenarios where one would perform better than other, so my main scenario is simple text search and retrieval through a couple million records. I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 as the DAL.

This is a concern and I would love some feedback on this from anyone having experimented or knowledgeable on this topic. Articles discussing varchar vs. nvarchar act like the SQL database is totally isolated in respect to performance and external software does not come into play. Is there in fact Unicode impedance mismatch between Windows native use of Unicode and ascii in the database, storage space and transfer speeds ignored, that negates the ascii database performance benefits? Especially in relation to EF? Thanks

Comment: Usually the main bottleneck is the database, not the client application. That's why a lot of people use languages like C# and Java for client applications, not C and assembler. Usually their performance is good enough. If your data is ASCII in the database, then process it as ASCII in the client application, do not convert it to Unicode. It is not clear why you want to convert ASCII to Unicode and back. Just work with ASCII everywhere, in the database and in the client application.

Comment: C# strings are Unicode and Entity Framework brings them in as Unicode to .NET String objects, so there is no choice.

Comment: Then your question becomes "how to work with ASCII strings in C# without converting them to Unicode" and "how to work with ASCII strings in EF". But first, I would try to measure how long it would take to convert a string (many strings) from ASCII to Unicode and back in C# and then decide whether it is significant enough to worry about.

Comment: Thx but I don't want to work with the data in C# as ASCII. I convert the ASCII data to C# strings when I first receive it then store it in the database via EF as .NET string objects.

Comment: More the second part you mention. I want to know if the required conversion between database ASCII strings and C# strings is worth the overhead as compared to the performance and space gains achieved keeping the database data as ASCII rather than Unicode. I know it depends, but was hoping someone had run some studies taking this into account rather than only comparing the performance gains within SQL Server void of application access. I've read SQL 2014 has better Unicode performance than SQL 2012 and we are in the midst of conversion.

Comment: I've to convert the nchar types to char types where there will never be Unicode need. I figure the space and sql performance are worth that. ANd keep a few lower volume fields as nchar types where they could potentially be Unicode some day. Thx for you input Vladimir.